# blogdown not showing plots from .Rmarkdown files but from .Rmd

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I'm using blogdown to create my website. Now I found this problem:

ggplots embedded in .Rmarkdown files doesn't appear. When I rename the file to .Rmd the graphic is okay. But I need to use .Rmarkdown because I want to use the beauty syntax highlighting and other features only available in .Rmarkdown files.

When I print the fig.path with

```
knitr::opts_chunk$get('fig.path')
```

I see the difference:
In .Rmd

```
"2020-06-17-rmd_files/figure-html/"
```

In .Rmarkdown

```
"/post/2020-06-17-rmarkdown_files/figure-html/"
```

But I don't see why the paths are changed.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution (at https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/raw-html-getting-omitted-in-0-60-0/22032):

After adding

```
[markup.goldmark.renderer]
  unsafe= true
```

in the config.toml the plots appear.